# How to interactively remove things from a GUI?

Tags: python, tkinter

So as it stands right now, I am trying to create a GUI will produce error codes when something goes wrong as a label with tkinter. But I also want to error code to go away if the error is resolved and the same button is pressed

My code;

```
def go(self):

    classname = cxml.classify()
    if type(classname) is str:
        missing = Label(self, text =
            """Invalid System Map.
             Please Double Check Inputs.
             If it needs to be added
            to a list, email me.""", fg='red')
        missing.place(x=275,y=75)
        time.sleep(15)
        missing.destroy()

    else:
        cxml.absolute_payer(classname,folder,file,person,place,thing)
        finished = Button(self, text = 'Done? Click here to Exit', command = lambda: exit())
        finished.place(x=50, y=150)
```

I have a button that reference the def go, and when I press it, I want it to remove the error code that may have been generated if the prior input resulted in an error.  If possible, I would prefer if the "go" button was the only button on the screen until the code executes properly.

The purpose would be to open the application and have the ability to produce different error codes (in the same location) within the GUI as long as it is kept open.

Comment: keep `missing` as `self.missing` and you will have access to this label in other functions. And don't use `sleep` because it blocks `mainloop` which get events, sends it to widgets, update data in widgets, and redraws widgets. Use `root.after(milliseconds, function_name)` to execute function which will remove label.

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked spectacularly